# How to show <?php tags in BBCode?

Tags: php, bbcode, phpbb

Is it possible to show `<?php` and `?>` tags in BBCode? I know about the `[code]` and `[php]` tags, but these still strip out any code blocks that contain things like:

```
<?php echo "myvalue" ?>
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: ok so stackoverflow stripped them too, not too surprising! How about this-- 
&lt;?php echo "myvar" ?&gt;

Comment: Well, it depends on what BBCode parser you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Here ( http://www.phpbb.com/community/faq.php?mode=bbcode#f2r1 ) is saying that you must use something like this [code=php][/code]
Try this maybe will work :)

Comment: Thanks D. Nope, I'm using a forum product called Kunena, I assume it uses a standard bbcode parser. Using the [code=php] syntax just changes the colors of the code highlighting, it still strips out anything with the <?php ?> format. (and stackoverflow stripped it on the preview, but shows it on publish. Pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

Oh and also you cand use markItUp! editor in your projects ( http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/ ) in this editor [code]< ? php echo "myvalue" ?>[/code] is working